# Style not applied to buttons in production

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a rails3 application that contains buttons. The font is not applied only to buttons after deploying to live server. However, The same font is applied to text messages. This problem do not arise in local. All is well in localhost.

Please suggest the solution.

Comment: what font you are using ?

Comment: can you please share some of your code, and also make sure you have uploaded that font on server.

Comment: I am using a font named "Ruluko". Yes the font si uploaded to server as it is applied to text messages. It only giving problem with buttons.

Comment: Code is:  <div class="body white right">
              <a class="activebtn sm fifth" onclick="return     display_only_pop_up('sign_up_popup',255,343);"  style="cursor:pointer">Sign up</a></div>

Comment: Css is .activebtn {
    font-family: RulukoRegular, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    clear:both;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
}